# How can render a video skipping frames based on any arbitrary rule?

Tags: python, video

Say I want to render every other frame in the first minute and only every third frame in the second etc?

Edit: 
I need the output to be one video.
Best way for me would be to generate an array of frame numbers and use only them in the rendered video.

Comment: Suggest try this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/114376/31447

Comment: Also related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47129/15543

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work like this

```
import bpy
#configure the startframe, endframe and the step size
render_list = [
#startframe, stopframe, step
[0, 50, 1] # Frame 0 to 50 with stepsize 1
[50, 100, 2] # Frame 50 to 100 with stepsize 2
]
for config in render_list:
     bpy.context.scene.frame_start = config[0]
     bpy.context.scene.frame_end = config[1]
     bpy.context.scene.frame_step = config[2]
     bpy.ops.render.render(animation = True) #execute animation with current settings
```

Comment: I got an error -  'scene' object has no attribute 'frame_stop'.

Comment: Did this on blender 2.8, in 2.79 it is frame_end

Comment: Tested against latest 2.8x, there is nothing like a `frame_stop` property so the code should be equal for both versions @miceterminator

Comment: Yep I must have screwed this up somehow. I'll change the answer

Comment: Now I got two videos, one for each brackets rule.

Comment: Well you join those videos again using the Videosequenceeditor or ffmpeg. Also I suggest rendering out to frames (so you have complete control) and then putting them into a video https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70774/how-can-i-turn-the-frames-rendered-by-blender-in-an-animation-into-a-video https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6082/rendering-into-video-with-blender-in-python-frames-to-video?rq=1